# Single page web app with fixed header and footer with twitter bootstrap library

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Basically I came up with following layout for my single page web app. I am unable to

1. Keep the footer fixed to the bottom of screen.
2. Remove white space between the two span classes caused by margin-left. This comes from responsive twitter css.
3. Scroll only the area between search box and bottom left footer.

[image]

I have basically have following layout

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <!--Search -->
            <!--scrollable div which doesn't scroll. Actually the scrollbar is for the html body instead of div-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span9"> <!--unnecessary postive value for margin-left -->
        <!--Header -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <!--unnecessary white space on the right -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                </div>
                <!--margin-left from twitter responsive css > 0 hence showing whitespace -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page layout is inspired by Steve Sanderson's full height app [layout](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/).

Comment: Anyone can give some directions ?